# image button onclick event not fired

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have created a HTML Image button in a web application with an `onclick` event handler. But the event is not firing. I am using the code below to create a button and its `onclick` event handler.

```
<input type="image" runat="server" src="Plan_search/images/buy.png" onclick="goto_click" />
 protected void goto_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
            try
            {

            }
            catch(Exception e1)
            {
                throw;
            }
  }
```

Comment: What is the rendered HTML of this? Have you checked, if there is an onclick-event in the rendered HTML? To me, it seems you are mixing up usual HTML and ASP.NET controls.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you want to use the OnServerClick attribute, rather than OnClick.

Comment: It returns the following error The server tag is not well formed.

Answer (score 2):

This is working code.Use this..

```
<input type="image" runat="server" src="Plan_search/images/buy.png"  onserverclick="goto_click" />

protected void goto_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        try
        {

        }
        catch(Exception e1)
        {
            throw;
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't create your button like `input` element.
Create your button like `ASP.NET` control:

```
<asp:ImageButton id="imagebutton1" runat="server"          
           ImageUrl="Plan_search/images/buy.png"
           OnClick="goto_click"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @samjudson suggested.
It should be

```
  <input id="Image1" type="image" runat="server" onserverclick="goto_click" />
```

But I think it should be using `ImageButton` rather than `image`

Answer (score -2):

You need parentheses:

```
goto_click()
```

And probably some arguments too.

Comment: where are you suggesting to write? it's a server side function rather than client side `javascript`